# Cypress for Firefox

Tags: firefox, cypress

Apparently from Cypress 4.0 the framework supports running the tests in major browsers.

The docs say all I need to do is to include `'cy:run:firefox': 'cypress run --browser firefox:dev'` in the `scripts` object within `package.json`.
That gives me browser couldn't be found in your system. I use it every day for my work so I'm
pretty sure it is installed on my system.
What can I do?

Comment: what is the need of firefox:dev? shouldn't that be firefox alone?

Comment: @Raju  The official docs say you should include exact version you're using (Firefox, Firefox:dev, Firefox:nightly)  I'm using dev version. But I did try to use just Firefox but got the same error.

Comment: Did you try launching it by passing the path to binary as given here? https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Launching-by-a-path Maybe, this will help in understanding the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

`cypress open --browser /opt/firefox_dev/firefox` did the trick for me.